# Delete/backup datebasefiles who aren't in the src folder

Tags: java, backup, derby

In my application I use a Derby database. Works without problems, but I'd like to make something in wich I can backup the complete database.

Now when I distribute my application, the Derby makes two files in a folder who is outside my .jar: derby.log & a directory called dbApplication.

The thing that I like to do is backup, delete and place the backup in the same path that the old one was. This is where my problem occurs:

I just dont know how to reach those files. I've no problems with reading files in my src or other packages(i.e. images/icons). Is it possible to reach those files, without knowing the exact location infront? Because the   .jar files can be place everywhere.

Comment: Find a way to backup now. Derby has its own methods for it. But restoring isnt working now. Can't shutdown my database

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking: how do I control the location of my derby.log file and my database folder?

Both of these can be configured to be placed in a location that you prefer.

To control the derby.log location, you can set the derby.stream.error.file property: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper18151.html

And you control the location of your database folder via your JDBC Connection URL. If you give a relative database name in the Connection URL, the database is located relative to Derby's system home: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper32066.html